# Notice: Undefined variable:_view in line

Tags: php, deprecated

Images on website won't display after updating php version for our domain. One of the errors is Notice: Undefined variable:_view in line 5. This is the code on line 5

```
<? if($_view!=null){$_view=$_view;}else {$_view=$_page;} ?>
```

this happened after updating php to newer version on our hosting site

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: Sorry new to the forum I though I did but here it is <? if($_view!=null){$_view=$_view;}else {$_view=$_page;} ?>

Comment: What's the point of `$_view = $_view;`? Anyway, use `!empty($_view)` instead of `$_view != null`.

Comment: Your upgrade probably changed the default `error_reporting` setting in php.ini. This was always getting an error, it was just silent about it before.

Comment: You need to put the code in a code block so it will be seen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting